# django factory boy couldn't import

Tags: django

I've created directory cheeses(myapp)/test/factories.py with code

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
import factory
import factory.fuzzy
from ..models import Cheese
class CheeseFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    name = factory.fuzzy.FuzzyText()
    slug = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda obj: slugify(obj.name))
    description = factory.Faker('paragraph', nb_sentences=3, variable_nb_sentences=True)
    firmness = factory.fuzzy.FuzzyChoice(
    [x[0] for x in Cheese.Firmness.choices]
    )
class Meta:
    model = Cheese
```

then in shel_plus i typed this
from cheeses.tests.factories.py import CheeseFactory
and got ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cheeses.tests.factories'; 'cheeses.tests' is not a package.
What have i done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `.py`. Means

```
from cheeses.tests.factories import CheeseFactory
```